# Login using webservice with a remote user database

Tags: c#, web-services, authentication

I have an online application with PHP & MySQL. I need to provide some functionality using a a desktop application built in C#. My task includes follwoing..

1. Authentication
2. Database query

Please suggest me a proper way to proceed with this scenario.

Some of my doubts..

- should I use webservice in my PHP end?
- How to authenticate?
- any security issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You will need to build a webservice on the PHP end, that contains a method that will execute your query. You can then add a ['Service Reference'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386382.aspx) in your C# application to the PHP service.

Regarding authentication: it depends on your scenario. If you are the only user of the webservice you can use [basic authentication](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html#basic) (over HTTPS) to ensure that your credentials are safe from sniffers.

Problem with security is that you will have to rely on tokens, keys, or something. And because these are stored on the desktop computer that uses the software, someone can steal these secrets (by using a decompiler f.e.). If security is really important, you will need to rely on 3rd party solutions like [DigiPass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digipass).

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Basically the app is multiuser and not going to store any credential on the system. We have a user management system with the back end with a mysql database. User has to be login by providing the credential when starting the app.

Comment: you do not have to store anything if you prompt the user's login and password each time the program is started.

Answer (score 1):

- Webservice: It is the standard way of working. But it has some overhead (XML and that all) so if you transmit complex structures you might need other options (passing data with your own codification over an HTTP connection, for example). Maybe even a mixed system were simple requests are through plain webservices and more complex ones go through HTTP but without using XML, or passing a structure codified this way inside the webservice. Anyway, try to keep non-standard solutions to a minimum.
- Depends of your security requirements. Webservices is HTTP, so the standard web authentication works.
- Same as before, you have the basic solution, it depends of what your application does.

Comment: That could be an example. Of course, you will need to interpret the JSON data in your program (by a third party library if it is available, or by code written by yourself).